# jQuery Validation validator.addMethod not being fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
$("#attribute-save-form").validate({            
    debug: false,
    rules: {
        txtAttributeName: "*",
        txtAttributeLabel: "*",
        txtLength: {
            NotEqualtoZero: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txtAttributeName: "*",
        txtAttributeLabel: "*",
        txtLength: {
            NotEqualtoZero: "Please enter length not equal to zero"
        }
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        $(validator.errorList).each(function (index, element) {
            element.message = "*";
        });
        ////
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(error).insertAfter(element);
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod("NotEqualtoZero", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || /[^0]/.test(value);
},  "Not Equal to zero.");

});
```

I don't know what mistake I'm making or what I'm missing but it is just displaying `*` error message and not the `"not equal to zero"`. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Update: I want to check that text value of text box is not equal to 0 
i have debugg it the problem is  in element my element "txtLength" is not coming

```
invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        $(validator.errorList).each(function (index, element) {
            element.message = "*";
```

my function "NotEqualToZero" is basically not being called here , am i missing somethig like i have include this in start

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        required: "*"
    });
```

is there anything else i have to include

Comment: update: iwant to check that text value of text box is not equal to 0

Comment: What is `txtAttributeName: "*"` supposed to be?

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML markup?

Comment: BTW, your code would be easier to read and troubleshoot if you'd take the time to format it properly... ie, proper indentation, remove blank lines and whitespace.

Comment: Please pay attention to my first two comments above.  Also explain the problem better.  Otherwise, your code, as you've posted it, is working exactly as it's programmed:  http://jsfiddle.net/tr22y/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works fine , my mistake was that i was giving element ids instead of element names in rules and messages in validate method, that's why add method was not calling.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NotEqualtoZero` rule is working perfectly fine and showing the `"Please enter length not equal to zero"` error in this simple demo.  Just enter `0` into the text box, click enter, and the error message appears:  **http://jsfiddle.net/tr22y/**

However `NotEqualtoZero` is ***optional*** unless you also specify the `required` rule.   In other words, there will be no error messages if you leave it blank.

The rest of your `rules`, however, do not make any sense at all.

```
rules: {
    txtAttributeName: "*",   // <- "*" is nonsense here
    txtAttributeLabel: "*",  // <- "*" is nonsense here
    txtLength: {
        NotEqualtoZero: true
    }
},
```

**There is no such rule as `*`**.  You have to enter the name of a single valid rule or `key:value` pairs of multiple valid rules.

Even so, that mistake still does not break anything.  I cannot see your HTML markup, nor can I know which rules you need, but with your present jQuery code, the `NotEqualtoZero` rule still works perfectly as designed...

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tr22y/2/**

**EDIT**:  After cleaning up the code in your question, you can also see that you have an extra `});` at the very end.  Perhaps you forgot the `$(document).ready(function() {` line from the top?  Maybe a cut & paste mistake when you posted the question?

Comment: I already had tested 'NotEqualToZero' on http://jsfiddle.net but the problem is It is not Working in my overall case, yes i have missed $(document),ready(function(){ from top its copy paste mistake

Comment: @tspga, then there is nothing more I can do for you.  I am showing you that the code is working, although `*` is not a valid rule, and you haven't explained what that's all about.  [BTW - this is your "overall case", as you've shown us, and it's working as expected: jsfiddle.net/tr22y/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/tr22y/2/)